# Facebook API - Mutual Friends

Tags: facebook, mutual-friendship

Is there a way to retrieve a list of mutual friends between /me/ and a certain {facebook id}

I thought this was possible with 1.0, but am wondering if it can still be done with 2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. Graph API v2.0 introduced a new endpoint

```
GET /{user-id}.context/mutual_friends
```

which is described at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/user.context/mutual_friends

There's a `summary.total_count` field in the result of the call which contains the number of mutual friends.

Comment: I am using the Graph API Explorer and entering:
 /v2.1/1191167455?fields=context.fields(mutual_friends)

It is giving me the following error:

{
  "error": {
    "message": "The global ID 1191167455 is not allowed. Please use the application specific ID instead.", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 2500
  }
}

Comment: When I use Mark Zuck's facebook id:

/v2.1/4?fields=context.fields(mutual_friends)

It displays:

{
  "context": {
    "mutual_friends": {
      "data": [
      ], 
      "summary": {
        "total_count": 0
      }
    }
  }, 
  "id": "4"
}

Comment: If you're using Graph API >=v2.0 then you need to use app-scoped ids. In the graph Explorer, change to one of your apps (pulldown in the upper right corner) which are >=v2.0 and retry. And, make sure to read the permission part of the docs I linked above.

Comment: I'm sorry...I don't understand how to use scoped ids.  Can you write a sample url that I can test in the Graph Explorer that will pull mutual friends with user id 1191167455

Answer (score 1):

There is a way in which you could get access to  all mutual friends (not only the ones using yout app) in API v2.

There is a special request. This is the detail:

> All Mutual Friends API
>
> The All Mutual Friends API gives you access to all the mutual friends
>   between two people who use your app. The response includes mutual
>   friends who use your app as well as limited information about mutual
>   friends who don’t use your app.
>
> Common Usage
>
> Display social context between the person using your app,
>   and another app user
>
> Use the token returned for non-app mutual friends
>   to link to that person's Facebook profile
>
> Surface the mutual friends
>   of two people who use your app to anyone other than those to people
>
> Store the names and profile pictures of the mutual friends
>
> Any
>   non-visible use of this information, for example for recommendations
>   and ranking

Here's the link:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/feature#reference-ALL_MUTUAL_FRIENDS

Comment: Could you provide a link to the API where you found this? It would greatly improve your post

Comment: Done. Thanks for the tip!